# AngularJS: Requisição $http para consumir API externa da do dominio dando erro

Tags: c#, angularjs, api, http-request

Eu tenho uma aplicação AngularJS que faz login. Eu estou tentando após o login, requisitar de uma API que estou rodando na minha máquina rodando em C# para ao menos conseguir se comunicar com ela. Porém deu diversos erros na minha tentativa, desde

```
  $http.get('http://localhost:5001/Login').then(function(data){
     console.log('entrou algo');
  }, function(data){ console.log(data); });
```

Erro 1: Pedido de origem cruzada bloqueado: A política de mesma origem não permite a leitura do recurso remoto em http://localhost:5001/Login. (Motivo: o pedido CORS não foi bem sucedido)

```
    $http({method:'GET',
           url: 'https://localhost:5001',   
           headers: 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'
         }).then(function(data){
        return data;        
    });
```

Erro2: Pedido de origem cruzada bloqueado: A política da mesma origem não permite a leitura do recurso remoto em https://localhost:5001/. (Motivo: cabeçalho CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' em falta).

Alguem poderia me ajudar?

Comment: tem que configurar o serviço para aceitar e liberar o `cors`!

Comment: Eu tentei colocar no index.php, no .htacess e ainda pela requisição e ainda continua com o erro. Não sei se fiz certo também...

Comment: o que haver index.php com C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu problema não parece ser originado no cliente onde o trecho em AngularJS está sendo executado.

Assumindo que sua API está escrita em .NET Core 3.1, a solução seria adicionar *policies* que permitem o acesso local.

Exemplo de configuração:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy(name: "Acesso Local",
            builder =>
            {
                builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost") // <- URL do conteúdo AngularJS
                        .WithMethods("PUT", "DELETE", "GET");
            });
    });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseCors();
}
```